# WebClient "error getting response stream"

Tags: c#, webclient

I've just got an error report from a client using a program I wrote, and I've been googling the nuts off of this error and can't find anything useful. The error is:

```
System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure ---> System.Exception:    at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError(WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String where)
   at System.Net.WebConnection.ReadDone(IAsyncResult result)
  at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError (WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String where) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFileCore (System.Uri address, System.String fileName, System.Object userToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.<DownloadFileAsync>m__F (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure ---> System.Exception:    at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError(WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String where)
   at System.Net.WebConnection.ReadDone(IAsyncResult result)
  at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError (WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String where) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFileCore (System.Uri address, System.String fileName, System.Object userToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.<DownloadFileAsync>m__F (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The application is the launcher program for a game, it pulls down a manifest of files and patches any which are non-existent or outdated. All the files it downloads with a WebClient object, it looks like the error is being thrown by WebClient::DownloadFileAsync, but I can't find any documentation as to why this could be happening.

Any help would be much appreciated, the quicker I can fix this monday morning the better!

Cheers
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the sysadmin played with the server config a bit this problem seemed to go away, I'm not sure exactly what was done though.

Answer (score 0):

Does the **client uses a proxy?**

If yes, are you attaching the proxy to the `WebClient` object?

Your error simply mentions that the file could not be found, `DownloadFileAsync` needs a file stream, and if that's not there, you get an error...

Any thoughts in implementing a log system that can be activate through a parameter that would POST the log file into your FTP for example?

You could make use of several open source projects out there, like [ExceptionReporter](http://exceptionreporter.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply =) 

Normally the file not being found has just resulted in WebClient.ResponseHeaders to be null.

I'll ask the client about proxies, but in order for execution to get to the DownloadFileAsync part of the code, it has to have first successfully called DownloadString getting a file from the same server.