# Webclient.UploadString gets System.Net.WebException:ReceiveFailure on subsequent call

Tags: c#, mono, debian, webclient, vps

I've written a .net 3.5 console application that fetch some data from a webpage. When debug and run on my Windows 7 development machine, it works fine.

But when it run on my hosted VPS running Debian 6.0.5 and Mono 2.6.7, it throws the following exception on 2nd or later call to `UploadString()`

```
System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure ---> System.Exception:    at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError(WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String where)
   at System.Net.WebConnection.ReadDone(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+SocketAsyncResult.Complete()
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+Worker.Receive()
  at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError (WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String where) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebClient.ReadAll (System.Net.WebRequest request, System.Object userToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataCore (System.Uri address, System.String method, System.Byte[] data, System.Object userToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadData (System.Uri address, System.String method, System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

My code is pretty straight forward (I have a try/catch/finally that dispose the webclient once done)

```
client = new WebClient();
client.Proxy = null;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx");
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string postString = "";
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in postData)
{
    postString += pair.Key + "=" + pair.Value + "&";
}
string content = client.UploadString(url, postString);
return content;
```

The above code is wrapped in a method, and is called many times for a list of data to be fetched. First call is always successful. On 2nd call onward, `UploadString()` will block for a good 30 seconds followed by the exception above. I notice this by watching the console output. If I left it running in a loop, after a few tries it will succeed and then fail again repeatedly.

I have another method which has similar code, but calling `OpenRead()` instead and return the content. This runs without any issues on my VPS. Also there's 2 PHP5 web application hosted on the VPS, running without any issue.

Since my VPS doesn't support X11 and I've no idea how to debug the code remotely using VS2010 (Or I should be using MonoDevelop). I'm hoping someone who had encountered a similar problem before has an answer to this, or some guide to debug this similar setup.

There's a similar question, [WebClient “error getting response stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454984/webclient-error-getting-response-stream)  but the answer is not helpful.
Thanks

EDIT: It slipped my mind that I could run MonoDevelop and debug on my development machine. Will do that now.

EDIT: Trying to debug using MonoDevelop + Mono 2.6.7 on Windows produces a diff set of problems, MySQL.Data unable to connect to server and WebClient gives timeout error.

I've resort to using HttpWebRequest and I get a similar exception when running on the VPS but not on my machine

```
System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure ---> System.Exception:    at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError(WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String where)
   at System.Net.WebConnection.ReadDone(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+SocketAsyncResult.Complete()
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+Worker.Receive()
  at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError (WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String where) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

HttpWebRequest is actually used in within WebClient, so getting the same exception seems reasonable.

EDIT: After being able to compile Mono 2.10.8 and run with it, I'm getting a different exception. Not sure if it's related to [Chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) but again, no such error when I debug in windows.

```
System.Net.WebException: An error occurred performing a WebClient request. ---> System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: The number of bytes to be written is greater than the specified ContentLength.
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.CheckWriteOverflow (Int64 contentLength, Int64 totalWritten, Int64 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.BeginWrite (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback cb, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataCore (System.Uri address, System.String method, System.Byte[] data, System.Object userToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadData (System.Uri address, System.String method, System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadData (System.Uri address, System.String method, System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadData (System.Uri address, System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadData (System.String address, System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString (System.String address, System.String data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.WebClient:UploadString (string,string)
```

EDIT: I'll get `ProtocolViolationException` if I'm using `WebClient` but I get `ReceiveFailure`, which is the same exception as earlier if I'm using HttpWebRequest, all on Mono 2.10.8

Comment: Have you tried using a REST client (there are several for chrome) to see if you can replicate the error outside of your code?

Comment: If you're referring to the webpage, I had a form in the page where I could submit some value to fetch the data, and that works, as well as running that application in windows, but not on Mono for windows though.

Comment: Can you try uploading the data using HttpWebRequest directly?

Comment: I guess will try that. Currently MonoDevelop is not helping as there's another issues with MySQL.Data when running Mono in Windows, and I'm getting timeout error from WebClient.

Answer (score 2):

I stopped reading when you mentioned you're using Mono 2.6.7. This version is more than two years old.

Before trying to find the culprit or add any workaround, you should first check if the problem still shows up in Mono 3.2, which is the last stable version (kind of LTS-like).

Comment: Thanks, I know it's old, but I'm running on Debian 6.0.5 (Latest non beta) and it only come standard with Mono 2.6.7. And I'm not using anything leading edge, so it should works. `WebClient` and `HttpWebRequest` is pretty standard stuffs so Mono shouldn't have left broken code in it for so long. Also, this is a production system, so I can't run Mono 3.0.3, which still beta. I'm currently trying to compile 2.10.8 and is having a hard time getting past `make`

Comment: Then post a question in StackOverflow about how to compile mono, it's that simple. BTW Mono 3.x is pretty much production ready if you don't use bleeding edge stuff such as sgen or c#async, we're using it in my company, take a look: http://blogs.7digital.com/dev/2012/09/25/atomic-mono-deployment-with-capistrano-and-nginx-under-debian/ (we also use Debian Squeeze)

Comment: Thanks, the compilation instruction given in Mono is broken and i just found that building mono from scratch is also broken too https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1442 :( Will try other ways

Comment: That is a bug in the monolite build. You can build mono without monolite (we do it this way).